# How to recover partially removed components of ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: 11.04, data-recovery

So I was messing around with `tasksel` to install LAMP. Foolishly I unchecked the `ubuntu-desktop` item. About 25% through the process I realized it is removing my desktop components. So I closed the terminal window, but now maybe something went wrong.

Many default applications are gone and I can't even boot into the desktop. I have a separate home folder so I don't really have to worry about data, but I did install a lot of other software which would be gone if I take reformat and reinstall. So is there a way to recover the desktop from a live CD?

Comment: Simply try reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage.

Comment: You should not have cancelled it midway, it could've possibly lead to a lot of complications. Letting it finish then reinstall the packages you want to retain would've worked smoothly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/578/discussion-between-roland-taylor-and-rick-2047)

Comment: I experienced the exact same scenario today. I managed to reinstall ubuntu-desktop but it was very broken so I decided to reinstall the system. This is a serious design flaw by tasksel. Usually when you opt-out for something in an installation process you expect it to opt-out for the install/reinstall - not completely remove what is already there. All I have to say now is thank god the ubuntu installer allows to reinstall the system without removing the home directory, but it is going to be a pain to reinstall and reconfigure my software.

Answer (score 1):

I will give it a shot.

- First, boot into the recovery console, then from there see if you can run metacity (at least): `metacity &`
- If this works, you can run synaptic (if it is still installed) from the command line: `sudo synaptic`
- From within synaptic, search for the Ubuntu Desktop package, and try to reinstall this (it will pull in dependencies automatically.
- If synaptic is not installed, you can run: `sudo apt-get install synaptic` and then follow the third step.
- After reinstalling the missing pieces, you should be able to log in again to your regular desktop (your settings will have been preserved of course).